# Can't accept answers

Tags: support, status-bydesign, answers

I can't accept any answers to my questions. I'm using Safari. The "check" button is not there. Instead, I just see a little flag that allows me to report things.

What am I missing here? I am a new user (3 day old account, 3 day old question), is there a time restriction I am not aware of?

I don't see this:

[image]

I read this page fully:
[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Which questions? None of your questions on the main site actually have answers, so there's nothing to accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The questions you have posted don't have answers. They only have comments.
If you see the upvote button + the little flag you describe, it's a comment, not an answer.

Answers can get upvoted, downvoted, and accepted. Comments can only get upvotes.

If someone comments an answer to your question, you can ask them to re-post it as an answer. Answers shouldn't be posted as comments.

<sub>By contrast, this is an answer, and you should be able to accept it if you want to</sub>

Comment: Got it! I never noticed the difference between a comment and an answer before. Thanks :)