# I am confused between answers and comments

Tags: discussion, meta

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [i have made an PNG to JPG converter in python.but when i open the file it says we don't support this file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415665/i-have-made-an-png-to-jpg-converter-in-python-but-when-i-open-the-file-it-says-w)

I am confused between answers and comments can you explain?

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388414/cant-accept-answers

Comment: Were you confused about the difference between the two in general or are you asking about the specific comments and answer you got where acw1668 said your existing code worked but Luke Weiler's answer said it didn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An answer is for someone to post what they believe is the solution to your problem. It's seen as a permanent artefact of the site - unless it doesn't actually answer the question in which case it could be deleted, but that's not really the point here. Answers should be complete and self contained and only use links to other sites (Wikipedia, documentation or blogs) as references and backup for what's being asserted in the answer. The answer should be useful despite the links, not because of them.

A comment is a place for someone to post something that's more temporary. It could be asking for clarification of part of your question or pointing out a typo in your code and so on. These are not permanent artefacts and can and should be removed as soon as they've fulfilled their purpose. So when you update your question you should flag the comments as "no longer needed" for example.

People will sometimes make suggestions in comments. This could be something that doesn't directly answer the question but could elicit more information which, in turn, could lead to an answer. Again, once it's fulfilled it's purpose it should be removed.

Comments are also the place where people can point you at other questions & answers on Stack Overflow that may help you with your problem.